# Zod: allow undefined as default value for a required field

Tags: typescript, zod

I have a simple form to "add/edit" an entity. My (simplified) `zod` schema looks like this:

```js
const schema = z.object({
  host: z.string(),
  port: z.number()
});
```

The default values for the "add" use case look like this:

```js
const defaultValues = {
  host: "Host"
};
```

**These are my requirements for the `port` field:**

- the field is required
- the field value is a number
- upon the "add" use case, it should be possible to provide an empty field to the user (so it would fail if the user hits submit before entering a value)
- it should be possible to set default values for other fields in the schema, without setting a value for the `port` field

So for the "add" use case most of the form fields should be empty (except the `host` field), only when i edit i want to set the current values for that entity as the default values.

The problem is, that `zod` won't allow this, as i must set a default value for the `port` field as it is a required field. From an UX perspective this isn't optimal, as i want to leave the `port` field empty and force the user to enter a value.

The only way i've found so far is to set the `port` field to `0`. But for the reason above this is not a good solution.

I wonder if there are other solutions to this problem? It seems like this shouldn't be rare case, as it is usually a requirement to pre-fill some fields, while other's must explicitly filled out by the user.

Comment: I think some context might be missing because it's not clear why you are parsing the user input before they try to submit. I would've expected that the editor logic would be using looser types and when the user goes to submit their edits, you would take the loose type and parse it with the zod schema. If it succeeds you would pass the information on to your request and if it fails you would translate the zod error into visual feedback to the user. At what point are you parsing the input?

Comment: @knoefel did you ever find a solution to this?

I literally have the same problem.  Need the value to be undefined to begin with but should validate as being filled in once the form is submitted.

Comment: @JustinYoung In my case i used remix and there was a [package](https://github.com/airjp73/remix-validated-form/blob/main/packages/zod-form-data/README.md#numeric) for handling this. Unfortunately i don't have access to the project anymore, so i can't share any code how i had set it up.